Suppressing or Handling @NamedQuery Exception Log During Spring Boot Startup
In my Spring Boot application, I encounter the following exception log during startup while initializing annotations like @NamedQuery:
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace

After investigating the related Hibernate class, I found that the buildNamedQuery method is explicitly designed to always throw this exception for stack trace purposes.
In my project, I do use JPA queries but do not utilize @NamedQuery annotations. While this log does not affect the application’s functionality, engineers from other teams often misinterpret it as a “real” error. This leads to repeated questions such as:

"Why is there an exception during server startup? Can you prove this is not an actual issue?"

To address this concern, is there a way to suppress this log or handle it more cleanly without relying on logger-level configuration (e.g., modifying logback.xml)?
Specifically, I’m looking for any Spring Boot or Hibernate configuration (e.g., application.yml) or other built-in mechanisms to address this.
If no such configuration exists, could you provide official documentation or references confirming that this log can safely be ignored? This would help resolve unnecessary confusion among engineers from other teams.
Thank you for your help!
I previously posted a question on the Hibernate forum regarding this issue, but I have not received any responses yet. Additionally, I have been unable to find any relevant information on this topic so far.

Please add the full log, not just the message. Provide more details about which Spring Boot and Hibernate versions you are using. You did investigate this already but failed to name the class which is doing this.
